# JSON date not showing in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a problem with JSON data: I want make news feed via JSON URL, but the information not showing in HTML.

```js
$(function() {

var entries = [];
var dmJSON = "http://www.stellarbiotechnologies.com/media/press-releases/json";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {

      var html = '<div class="panel-body"><h3 class="lead">${title}</h3>';

      html += '<time datetime="${published}">';
      html += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> ';
      html += '<span class="month">${monthName}</span> ';
      html += '<span class="day">${day}</span>, ';
      html += '<span class="year">${year}</span></time></div>';
 $('#ticker').html

    },
```

```html
<div id="ticker"></div>
```

Comment: `${title}`? `${published}`?  Are you using some kind of template library?

Comment: `$('#ticker').html`... Then what?

Comment: You're appending everything to the `html` var, but then not actually using it. Maybe you want  `$('#ticker').html(html)` And you're not actually looping through the returned `data`.

Comment: thanks for replying , ${title} insiad json , in fact i don't know how i programming , i just need some one  he make the code correct .

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var dmJSON = "http://www.stellarbiotechnologies.com/media/press-releases/json";
    $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {

          var html = '';

            // loop through all the news items, and append the 
            // title and published date to the html variable.

            for(var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++){

                html += '<div>';
                html += data.news[i].title 
                html += '<br>';
                html += data.news[i].published 
                html += '</div>';
            }

            // append all the html variable to the ticker div.
            $("#ticker").append(html);
        });

 });
</script>
```

This will loop through the `news` node, and get the `title` and the `published` date and then append them to the page (an element with the `id` of `ticker`.

Comment: thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk you very mush he worked :) one love man